# Can we change a picture in a Google Doc dynamically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am coding a contract application in Google App Script.

It creates a GoogleDoc from a template that include an image of the seller's signature and initials.

As there are five seller, and a dozen different templates, is there a way to change the image of signature and initials?

I have no clues where to start looking for that.

thanks and have a nice day!

- Eric

EDIT : I found something about InlineImage in DocumentApp... still looking

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code which appends a an image in a Google doc. Hope this will give you Idea to get going.
Similar concept I used to make a [resume builder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sbc-resume-builder/lednmppbbboaelhfolehbdeapnkocneg) application which replaces Profile picture and a signature image

```
//Make a UI form to upload Image
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  //Form
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setEncoding('multipart/form-data').setId('form');
  //Add this form to the application
  app.add(form);

  //Panel to hold form elements
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  //add this panel inside form
  form.add(panel);

  //Now create form elemnts
  var label1 = app.createLabel('Upload Image');
  var uploadControl = app.createFileUpload().setName('file').setId('file');
  var submitBtn = app.createSubmitButton('Submit');
  //Add all these elemnts to the panel
  panel.add(label1).add(uploadControl).add(submitBtn);

  //Return the application to the service URL
  return app;
}

//This function is callend when the form is submitted
function doPost(e){
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.file; //This is the image blob if an image is uploded

  //Open the document
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('ID OF GOOGLE DOC')//change Id of the document
  //get the body of document
  var docBody = doc.getActiveSection();
  //Append the iamge in document body
  docBody.appendImage(fileBlob);
  //Save and close the document
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll see if that leads me somewhere. I might be able to cycle through the sections and find the one where the images are, then change it...